How to add trend line to exponential data in {ggplot2}?
I am trying to add a trend line to my {ggplot2} plot using ggplot2::geom_smooth(). I have tried multiple times to add the line but have not been able to figure it out. Here is my most recent attempt.
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  year = 2014:2023,
  totglp = c(27, 73, 125, 225, 266, 368, 466, 820, 1383, 2167)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = totglp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ exp(x), se = FALSE)
#> Warning: Failed to fit group -1.
#> Caused by error in `lm.wfit()`:
#> ! NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'


Created on 2024-06-23 with reprex v2.1.0.9000

Hi Preston Carey, welcome to SO. Please do not add data as an image for these reasons. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. In your case, you could run dput(IIHGLPy) and add the result to a codeblock in your question. The result will look something like structure(list(...)). Thanks

Try using method=loess and drop the formula variable.

That code is producing infinite values (i.e., Inf) when you attempt to exponentiate the year values and thus errors that prevent drawing a line.
Instead of exponentiating the predictors, you might instead try logging the outcomes (i.e., formula = log(y) ~ x). While this will draw a trend line, it won't translate the log(y) values back to the original, non-logged scale when plotting because this is not a feature of a linear model (i.e., lm).
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  year = 2014:2023,
  totglp = c(27, 73, 125, 225, 266, 368, 466, 820, 1383, 2167)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = totglp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = log(y) ~ x, se = FALSE)


Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0.9000
As an alternative, you could manage the model fitting and back translation yourself and then use geom_function().
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  year = 2014:2023,
  totglp = c(27, 73, 125, 225, 266, 368, 466, 820, 1383, 2167)
)

# fit the model outside of ggplot
m <- lm(log(totglp) ~ year, data)

# make a function that predicts on the original, non-logged scale
trend <- function(x, m) {
  d <- data.frame(year = x)
  log_pred <- predict(m, newdata = d)
  exp(log_pred)
}

# and use geom_function()
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = totglp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_function(fun = trend, args = list(m = m), color = "blue")


Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0.9000
But that's a bit of coding. So instead you could fit a Gaussian generalized linear model (GLM) with a log link function. This both accounts for the loglinear relationship via the link function and will also translate the predictions back to the original, non-logged scale when plotting because this is a feature of a GLM (i.e., glm).
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  year = 2014:2023,
  totglp = c(27, 73, 125, 225, 266, 368, 466, 820, 1383, 2167)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = totglp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "glm", 
    formula = y ~ x, 
    se = FALSE, 
    method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = "log"))
  )


Created on 2024-06-23 with reprex v2.1.0.9000
Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub

Year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)
TotGLP = c(27, 73,  125, 225, 266, 368, 466, 820, 1383, 2167) 

IIHGLPy = data.frame(Year, TotGLP) 

ggplot(IIHGLPy, aes(x=Year, y=TotGLP)) +
  geom_point(shape=18, color="black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ exp(x), se = FALSE, color = "blue") +
  labs(title = "GLP-1 Agonist Trend in IIH Patients", 
       x = "Years", y = "Total Number of Patients on GLP-1 Aogonists")

will yield an error:
Warning message:
Failed to fit group -1.
Caused by error in `simpleLoess()`:
! NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2) 

because
exp(IIHGLPy$Year)
 [1] Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf

This works:
ggplot(IIHGLPy, aes(x=Year, y=TotGLP)) +
  geom_point(shape=18, color="black") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, color = "blue") +
  labs(title = "GLP-1 Agonist Trend in IIH Patients", 
       x = "Years", y = "Total Number of Patients on GLP-1 Aogonists")


 

